# Изменение формулы расчета значения переменной в зависимости от вводимых данных в поле input

Tags: jquery, переменные, if

На днях подкинули небольшую задачку по созданию калькулятора. Вроде бы ничего сложного, но...

Есть некий принтер с шириной печати 3.2 м. Задается длина и ширина изделия, после чего, бОльшую сторону этого изделия мы делим на 3.2 - получается наименьшее количество необходимых для склейки швов. 
Итого, для размеров 3х12 мы выполняем 12 / 3.2, а для размеров 10*4 - 10 / 3.2.

Не удается задать формулу переменной, которая бы менялась в зависимости от веденных значений полей input ("dlin","shir"). В результате, не запускается функция if и формула расчета не меняется. Получается, что всегда делится длина (первая инструкция if).

Как решить данную проблему?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function bansol() {
    var dlin = $('#dlin').val().replace(',', '.');
    var shir = $('#shir').val().replace(',', '.');
    $mate = $('select#mate option:selected').attr('data-mate');
    var price = dlin * shir * $mate;
    var newprice = Math.ceil(price);
    var rulo = 3.2;

    if (dlin >= shir) {
      shvii = dlin / rulo;
    } else if (dlin < shir) {
      shvii = shir / rulo;
    }
    $('.shvi').html(shvii);
    $('.cur').html(newprice);
    $('.rub').show();
  };
  $('.calculator').on('click keyup', bansol);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вызвать `Math.min` или `Math.max` она сама преобразует строки в числа.
Я так и не понял написано большую сторону, но минимальное число швов.

```js
function bansol() {
  var dlin = $('#dlin').val().replace(',', '.');
  var shir = $('#shir').val().replace(',', '.');
  
  var rulo = 3.2;
  shvii = Math.min(dlin, shir) / rulo;

  $('.shvi').html(shvii);
};

$('.calculator').on('click keyup', bansol);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="dlin">
<input id="shir">

<p class="shvi"></p>

<button class="calculator">считать</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Сравнивайте числа, а не строки.

```
var dlin = +$('#dlin').val().replace(',', '.');
var shir = +$('#shir').val().replace(',', '.');
```